# Comparing the individual values in two separate files such that if same, assign value 0 else 1 in python

Tags: python

I am quite new to programming (Python) and I am trying to write a script in python that compares the values in two separate files such that if the value is the same it assigns 0, and it the value is different it assigns 1.

Say the both initial files are 4rows by 3 columns, so the final file will be a 4rows by 3 columns file of just 1’s and 0’s.

Also, I'd like to sum all the values in this new file (that is summing all the 1’s together).

I have checked around, and I have come across functions such as 'difflib', however I don't know if that'll be suitable.

I am wondering if anyone can help out with something simple...

Thanks a lot in advance :)

The both files shown below consist of 5rows and 6columns

`File 1 (ain.txt) 
0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 0`

`File 2 (bin.txt)
1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0`

The script below outputs True and False...

```
import numpy as np

infile = np.loadtxt('ain.txt')
data = np.array(infile)

infile1 = np.loadtxt('bin.txt')
data1 = np.array(infile1)

index = (data==data1)

np.savetxt('comparrr.txt', (index), delimiter = ' ', fmt='%s')
```

The output shown below:

```
comparrr.txt

FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
```

However I would want the "FALSE" to be represented by values of 1, and the "TRUE" by values by 0.

I hope this clarifies my question.

Thanks very much in advance.

Sorry for all the troubles, I found out the issue with the previous script above was the format I chose (fmt='%s')... changing that to (fmt='%d') gives the output as 1's and 0's... however I want to have them flipped (i.e. the 1's become 0's, and the 0's become 1's)
Thanks

The output after the change in format mentioned above, shown below:

```
0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what your files look like. Copy and paste their text here so we know how they're structured.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: Ok, updating answer

You don't need to import `numpy` to solve this problem.

If you open the files in [iter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) they will be read line by line as strings. You can use [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to make them into a list and then use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and list comps to quickly figure out if they're equal or not. Then you can turn it back into a string(with [map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)) and toss it into the file.

```
foo1 = iter(open('foo1', 'r'))
foo2 = iter(open('foo2', 'r'))

outArr = [ [0 if p==q else 1 for p,q in zip(i.split(), j.split()) ] for i,j in zip(foo1,foo2) ]

totalSum = sum([ sum(row) for row in outArr ])

with open('outFile', 'w') as out:
   for row in outArr:
      out.write(' '.join(map(str,row))+'\n')
```

In regards to your code--while the `index = (data==data1)` bit technically works because of how [numpy arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) work, it isn't very readable in my opinion.

To invert your array, numpy provides `invert` which can be applied directly to the numpy array as `np.invert(index)`. Also, `np.loadtxt()` returns an [`np.ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) type, you don't need to reassign it. To make your code work as you have outlined I would do the following...

```
import numpy as np

infile = np.loadtxt('foo1')    
infile1 = np.loadtxt('foo2')

index = np.invert(infile==infile1).astype(int)
totalSum = sum(sum(index))

np.savetxt('outFile', index, fmt='%d')
```

Comment: How would I sum the values in the "index", and then write it into a file? In the example shown, the sum should be 11, so 11 should be written in the file.

Comment: @user3594875 Sorry, forgot to include the sum, fixed. Also, the sum should be 19 for the inverted case

Comment: Yes sure I have, but what if I want to write that "totalSum" into a file? Using    np.savetxt('tsum.txt', totalSum,fmt='%d') is giving me     Index: tuple index out of range

Comment: Just use the python builtin [write()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) function, you're only writing a single line to a file for totalSum. See my first solution without using numpy for how to write to a single file. You have to get more accustomed to looking at documentation for things you're using, [np.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) wants an array type passed to it where you're passing totalSum, which is an integer.

Answer (score -1):

```
'''
assume file 'a.txt' is:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
'''

# 1. read in two file.
with open('a.txt','r') as fa:
    a = [map(int, line.split()) for line in fa]

with open('b.txt','r') as fb:
    b = [map(int, line.split()) for line in fb]

# 2. compare values in two files.
sum_value = 0
c = []
for i in range(4):
    c.append([])
    for j in range(3):
        if (a[i][j] == b[i][j]):
            c[i].append(1)
            sum_value += 1
        else:
            c[i].append(0)

# 3. print comparison array.
print c
# 4. print sum value.
print sum_value
```